# Android trying to read image in res/drawable-nodpi-v4/ but that directory doesn't exist in my project

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

Crashlytics is telling me that my app is crashing when it tries to inflate a particular layout because it can't find the `image_uparrow.xml` image in the `res/drawable-nodpi-v4/`.

But I don't have a `res/drawable-nodpi-v4/` directory. The only version of `image_uparrow.xml` in my entire project is in `res/drawable-nodpi/` without the `-v4`.

That `image_uparrow.xml` is a `selector` that (oddly) has only one entry in it (must have been an old refactoring artifact or something).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/uparrow" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

And `@drawable/uparrow` has two possibilities:

- `res/drawable-mdpi/uparrow.png`
- `res/drawable-hdpi/uparrow.png`

---

So, beyond the weirdness of having only one item in the `selector`, why on earth would the system try to open a file in `res/drawable-nodpi-v4` when I don't even have that directory in my project at all?

---

Here's the crash stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator:layout/deletereorder_cell: Binary XML file line #10 in com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator:layout/deletereorder_cell: Error inflating class ImageButton

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator:layout/deletereorder_cell: Error inflating class ImageButton

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator:drawable/image_uparrow with resource ID #0x7f0800d0

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-nodpi-v4/image_uparrow.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800d0
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:874)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:668)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:993)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:982)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:204)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:78)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:253)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:168)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
       at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity.addCashFlowRow(CashFlowActivity.java:349)
       at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity.addAllCashFlowRows(CashFlowActivity.java:212)
       at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity.touchedDeleteReorderButton(CashFlowActivity.java:201)
       at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(CashFlowActivity.java:126)
       at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4343)
       at ...
```

The part of the layout xml that is having the problem is:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/upButton"
    style="@style/Cashflow.ReorderButton.Up"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/move_row_up" />
```

Here's the referenced style, which is where the image is defined:

```
<style name="Cashflow.ReorderButton.Up">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/image_uparrow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This look very similar to another posting I've been working on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323494/android-build-error-error-inflating-class-imageview-cant-import-xml-files-fro#comment136329876_77323494 Both postings are having issue inflating an image in android.  The other posting looks like there is an issue cast one image type to another type.